# Is $W$ a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I wanted to determine if $W$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$:

$W=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:x\leq y\leq z\}$.

I believe that it is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ since I think it satisfies all the conditions (contains the zero vector, is closed under addition and scalar multiplication), is this assumption correct?

Thank You!

Comment: It's not closed under scalar mutliplication.

Comment: Is it because this inequality limits you only to numbers less than or equal to zero, meaning that if you multiply it, it will surpass the given space?

Comment: You have to allow for multiplication by negative scalars as well as non-negative scalars.

Answer (score 3):

If $(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3$ satisfies the inequality, multiplying it by the scalar $-1\in\mathbb{R}$ will reverse the inequality.

Answer (score 0):

$\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\3\end{bmatrix}$ is an element of $W$ since $1\leq 2\leq 3$ (*it satisfies $x\leq y\leq x$*)

Is $-1\cdot \begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\3\end{bmatrix}$ an element of $W$?

> Is it true that $-1\leq -2\leq -3$?